# execute a batch file in maven during compile

Tags: java, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

I'm using the exec-maven-plugin to execute a batch file with maven.  I had it running during the package phase, but I need it to run earlier.  The compilation phase would be fine.

The batch script generates a properties file that contains the svn version.  When the phase is set to package, it looks like is does this *after* it makes the war file.  Too late for me.

However, in eclipse I get this error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (execution: Version, phase: compile)
```

The relevant section of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>Version</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
     <executable>\my\path\version\version.bat</executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

First, is exec-maven-plugin still the right tool?

Second, can it be run during an earlier phase than package?  Is this documented anywhere?  The mailing list archive links on the exec-maven-plugin project page are out of date.

Comment: Why do you need such batch file, cause this will make your build not portable anymore. Apart from that what are doing with the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `exec-maven-plugin` but with `m2e` plugin which doesn't know what to do with `exec-maven-plugin`. The simplest way to fix the problem is to ignore that plugin during build *within Eclipse* (right click on the problem and use a proposed solution). Command-line invocation will still run the batch.

If you wish `m2e` can be configured more sophisticately. Take a look on the snippet from one of my projects:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <!-- The following plugin is solely to make Eclipse happy, it's not executed during regular build -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.cmake-maven-project</groupId>
                <artifactId>cmake-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[2.8.11-b4-SNAPSHOT,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute />
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Also you may run virtually any goal of any plugin during any phase or completely disable its execution. Here I disable `default-deploy` of the `maven-deploy-plugin` and assign a customized goal `deploy-file` to the `deploy` phase:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-deploy</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>versioned-deploy</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <configuration>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}</repositoryId>
            <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
            <generatePom>false</generatePom>
            <pomFile>${effective_dir}/pom.xml</pomFile>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

There's a special `mvn help:effective-pom` command which allows you to understand what is the final configuration of a mavenized project.